# Excluir informação de data de expiração em posts Wordpress

Tags: php, datetime, wordpress

Estou usando o código abaixo para informar o tempo que leva para um post expirar no meu site Wordpress, cujo valor de expiração eu defino em um Custom Field (expiration).

A partir desse código, como eu evito que um post que vá expirar daqui a 4 horas, não seja exibido a informação desta forma: "Expira em 0 dias, 4 horas e 49 minutos".

Eu não quero que o "0 dias" seja exibido, apenas as horas restantes. No caso de o post expirar no dia seguinte, aí tudo bem, poderia ser exibido normalmente "Expira em 1 dias, 4 horas e 49 minutos".

Além disso, há posts que eu não defino expiração, e em todos eles aparece a seguinte informação: "Expira em 0 dias, 2 horas e 0 minutos". Como faço para exibir uma informação como "Expiração indeterminada" para esses posts?

```
           <?php 
                $date_now    = date( 'd/m/Y H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
                $date_expire = get_field('expiration');

                $now     = new DateTime($date_now);
                $expires = new DateTime($date_expire);

                $diff = $expires->diff($now)->format("%a dias, %h horas e %i minutos");

                if ($now < $expires) {
                    echo "Expira em $diff", PHP_EOL;
                } 
                else if ($now >= $expires) {
                    echo "Expirado!", PHP_EOL;
                }
                else {
                    echo "", PHP_EOL;
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz assim coloca o dia em uma variavel $dia. e checa se ela for 0 ela não mostra o dia.

```
<?php
$date_now    = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', current_time('timestamp', 0));
$date_expire = get_field('expiration');

$now     = new DateTime($date_now);
$expires = new DateTime($date_expire);

$dia = $expires->diff($now)->format("%a");

if ($dia != 0) {
    $diff = $expires->diff($now)->format("%a dias, %h horas e %i minutos");
} else {
    $diff = $expires->diff($now)->format("%h horas e %i minutos");
}

if ($now < $expires) {
    echo "Expira em $diff", PHP_EOL;
} else if ($now >= $expires) {
    echo "Expirado!", PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "", PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda, TutiJapa.